# Why is OPENFILENAME lpstrFileTitle param a LPSTR and not LPCSTR?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am creating some file open dialog and stumbled across something inconsistent in the WinAPI (hehe).

I fully understand why `lpstrFile` is a `LPSTR` as the path is written into this variable.

Fine, but why is `lpstrFileTitle` not `LPCSTR`? I've read the docs at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and googled around and found no satisfying explanation as it doesn't look like it is modified in any way.

Is this a compatibility remnant or something?

Causes annoying workarounds when passing a std::string as I cannot use `c_str()` and resort to `&str[0]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`lpstrFileTitle` is also an output buffer. It contains the name and extension without path information of the selected file.

Comment: I was just editing my post as I also realized that. Would have expected MSDN to hint it in a similar way than `lpstrFile`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Related side-note: You must set lpstrFileTitle to a valid buffer for non-Unicode builds.

The docs for OPENFILENAME state that field is ignored if the pointer is null.  However, since at least VS2008 the MFC CFileDialog code has included this code:

```
VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\dlgfile.cpp
void CFileDialog::UpdateOFNFromShellDialog()
{
...
#ifdef UNICODE
...
#else
    ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wcPathName + offset,-1, m_ofn.lpstrFileTitle, m_ofn.nMaxFileTitle, NULL, NULL);
    m_ofn.lpstrFileTitle[m_ofn.nMaxFileTitle - 1] = _T('\0');
#endif
...
```

The Unicode support correctly handles a NULL lpstrFileTitle and the WideCharToMultiByte basically does nothing.  However, the added code to safely terminate the buffer does not check for a null pointer or a nMaxFileTitle==0.  The result is an access violation.

Better of course to kill multibyte apps, but if you must compile that way, you have to supply that buffer.